# can't create a new Zebble project

Tags: xamarin-zebble, zebble

I've just started learning Zebble and installed all dependencies
and then I downloaded all extensions, but when I restart the vs 2019 and try to create a new zebble project, I can't even find zebble framework in the list, I also tried to find it by search but nothing appeared

I checked extensions and Zebbe is installed

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You should install zebble-build package and create your project with command line